# Firebase Firestore : Creating collection inside a document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a collection inside a document.

my data model looks like this.

[image]

```
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('properties')
      .doc(selectedPropertyId)
      .collection('companies')
      .doc()
      .set({
     ...
      },
        { merge: true },
      );
```

for some reason its not creating collection under specific document.

it created collection at parent level with `id undefined`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet that `selectedPropertyId` is actaully the string "undefined".  And, if you click into "undefined" in the console, you will see the "companies" subcollection, along with the document you created.

If this is the case, you will want to investigate why `selectedPropertyId` is not the value you expect.

Comment: that sounds like me: ) but selectedPropertyId has the propertyId value that I am looking.

Comment: Then it is not creating that undefined document ID.  Something else is doing that.

Comment: .firestore()
      .collection('properties')
      .doc(selectedPropertyId) this part find the property and then 'companies' create collection and then following values add the actual document. am I right ?

Comment: `collection()` and `doc()` just build a reference to a document - they haven't created anything yet.  The call to `set()` will create the document at reference.

Comment: Nevermind, i found the problem, it wasn't the query if was never hitting that condition,

Comment: Could you please post an answer with what solved your issue and this might help other Community Members with any similar issue ? Thanks